# How to unmerge and fill cells in an excel file while loading into datatable

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel file as show below
[image]

I use the following code to load the file into a data table.

```
string sSheetName= GetSheetName(); // Get data sheet name 
string connString = GetConnString(); // get excel connect string 
OleDbConnection  objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString); 
OleDbDataAdapter impDataAdapter; 
objConn.Open(); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
DataTable dtMap = new DataTable();
impDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + sSheetName + "]", objConn); 
impDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

After loading the data table it looks like this

[image]

what I really want is this

[image]

So is there any way I could unmerge the cells and duplicate the data in merged cells using C#?

Comment: It can be done with formula, without c#